# Selenium Accessing ShadowRoot Google Chrome Printing Excel VBA Type Mismatch Error 13

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to reference a shadowroot element in the Google Chrome print window to eventually change the print scaling in a printing application in Excel VBA. Code excerpt below. My research shows variable and return not matching is what causes this error, however I set the WebElement as the variable type and am returning a WebElement.

```
       Private CADSite As Selenium.ChromeDriver
       Sub CADSheetPull()
       Dim FullWeb As String
       FullWeb = "https://www.google.com"
       Dim PrintPreviewApp As Selenium.WebElement
       Set CADSite = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
       CADSite.Start
       CADSite.Get FullWeb
       SendKeys "^p"
       CADSite.SwitchToNextWindow
       'Error Line
       Set PrintPreviewApp = CADSite.ExecuteScript(Script:="return arguments[0].shadowRoot", Arguments:=CADSite.FindElementByCss("print-preview-app"))
```